# Shard is in "recovery" replicas are all "active"

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I would like to know what I can do about this situation, all of the replicas show "active" by the state of the shard is "recovery" and all of replicas are “active”. The shard is unavailable for queries or indexing.

```
   <lst name="shard2">
        <str name="range">d5550000-2aa9ffff</str>
        <str name="state">recovery</str>
        <lst name="replicas">
             <lst name="core_node2">
                <str name="core">Master_shard2_replica2</str>
                <str name="base_url">http://10.3.197.199:8983/solr</str>
                <str name="node_name">10.3.197.199:8983_solr</str>
                <str name="state">active</str>
             </lst>
             <lst name="core_node11">
                <str name="core">Master_shard2_replica1</str>
                <str name="base_url">http://10.3.198.173:8983/solr</str>
                <str name="node_name">10.3.198.173:8983_solr</str>
                <str name="state">active</str>
                <str name="leader">true</str>
             </lst>
        </lst>
   </lst>
```

EDIT: Solr 6.5.1 and Zookeeper 3.4.6

Comment: Please share which version of Solr you are using and which version of ZooKeeper (if it's a standalone ZooKeeper variant)?

Comment: Edited to include that information.

Comment: Have you checked the Zookeeper logs for any errors - zookeeper is supposedly the maintainer of the state (told to it by Solr) so that's the first place I would look.